# Page borders gone in evince after 14.04 upgrade

Tags: 14.04, themes, evince

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, the thin black borders that appear around pages in evince have disappeared. Now, when I'm reading a pdf file in evince, the pages appear white against a background that's very slightly pink, but without the page border you have to squint to see the boundary between the page and the background. The result when viewing documents in continuous mode is that there appear to be big chunks of needless white space in the middle of the document (where in fact there is merely a page boundary), and it looks rather odd.

I don't want to turn off continuous mode, and apart from this I think evince is brilliant, so I'd be very reluctant to change pdf viewer.

Is this change in appearance caused by the new default theme in 14.04 (with its lack of borders)? What can I do to get back my bordered documents?

Comment: same here...any luck so far?

Answer (score -1):

Change the theme from "Ambiance" to "Adwaita" solved the problem for me.  But you have to like this new theme.

Comment: You can change the theme only for the windows decorations using unity tweak tool.  It works the same and you can keep the standard set of icons.